# How to perform status checks in github repository

Tags: git, github, version-control, repository, status

I have a GitHub repository in which I protected one branch with the new feature of [Protected Branches](https://github.com/blog/2051-protected-branches-and-required-status-checks).

Now my problem is that I wish to perform the status check in the system and then commit and push it to the GitHub repo.

Problem: where do I perform such status checks and how do I send the message to the GitHub server that the status checks have been cleared?

Comment: Check this link from Github which shows you what to do for setting up status checks; https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/administering-a-repository/enabling-required-status-checks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> where do I perform such status checks

In the same place you [set up status checks](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/administering-a-repository/enabling-required-status-checks): settings/branches (select your branch)

> and how do I send the message to the GitHub server that the status checks have been cleared

Those checks are updated when you push from your local repo to that branch.

---

In order to send a success status, you can follow [Building a CI server](https://developer.github.com/guides/building-a-ci-server/): it will use the Status API.
The [Status API](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/statuses/) is responsible for tying together commits with a testing service, so that every push you make can be tested and represented in a GitHub pull request.

```
def process_pull_request(pull_request)
  @client.create_status(pull_request['base']['repo']['full_name'], pull_request['head']['sha'], 'pending')
  sleep 2 # do busy work...
  @client.create_status(pull_request['base']['repo']['full_name'], pull_request['head']['sha'], 'success')
  puts "Pull request processed!"
end
```

> We're doing three very basic things here:
>
> - we're looking up the full name of the repository
> - we're looking up the last SHA of the pull request
> - we're setting the status to "success"

Comment: I am sorry...but i don't understand, I have seen the documentation in ur link, but it does not tell me how can i actually code to get parameters, process and then send success response...??\

Comment: @VineetVerma I have edited the answer to add the documentation regarding the server CI which can listen to your "succes" update. It means you need to setup said server CI (Continuous Integration) listener.

Comment: Lolz VonC...u r providing me only references from the documentation...Not useful

Comment: @VineetVerma did you follow that documentation? Did you setup a CI listener as mentioned in the documentation?

Comment: I am already on that..till now failing @ Octokit initialization

Comment: @VineetVerma Then you can make a new question for that.