# Python GitHub "Status Check" POST Not Found Error! (404)

Tags: github-api, pull-request

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34946194/how-to-perform-status-checks-in-github-repository): "*How to perform status checks in github repository?*" ..

**References** the following articles:

https://help.github.com/en/github/administering-a-repository/enabling-required-status-checks
https://developer.github.com/v3/guides/building-a-ci-server/#working-with-statuses

So, to update a **status check**, I need to create one (and update it with a status at the same time); as per: https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/statuses/#create-a-status ... Issue a `POST` to:

```
/repos/:owner/:repo/statuses/:sha
```

However, I am getting a **404** (`response.status_code: 404`), whenever I try to post a payload to the endpoint url.
**NOTE**: I am building the url, using the information from the GitHub web-hook itself i.e.

```
content['repository']['owner']['login']
content['repository']['name']
content['pull_request']['head']['sha']
```

**JSON** Payload:

```
payload = { "state": "pending", "description": "The build succeeded!", "context": "continuous-integration/audit-compliance"}
```

**Request**:

```
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                       'Authorization': "token "+gittokn}
url = https://github.com/api/v3/repos/<OWNER>/<REPO>/statuses/<PR-HEAD-SHA>
response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=payload, verify=False)
```

**Response**:

```
{'message': 'Not Found', 'documentation_url': 'https://developer.github.com/enterprise/2.18/v3/repos/statuses/#create-a-status'}
```

With **Curl**:

```
curl -Is --user USER:PASS https://github.com/api/v3/repos/<OWNER>/<REPO>/statuses/<PR-HEAD-SHA> | head -1
    HTTP/1.1 200 OK

curl -Is --user USER:PASS https://api.github.com/repos/<OWNER>/<REPO>/statuses/<PR-HEAD-SHA> | head -1
# no result
```

Where am I going wrong?

Can provide additional info on request; TIA.

Comment: ```Users with push access in a repository can create commit statuses for a given SHA.

``` Do you have that access ?

Comment: which parameters do you supply in post request ?

Comment: @AndriyIvaneyko thanks.. I have updated the question to include the parameters. And yes, I have push access to the repository.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See that in the example the url has no v3 prefix, the template below shall work for you:

`https://api.github.com/repos/ORGNAME/REPONAME/statuses/<SHA>`

## UPDATED ANSWER

https://github.com/api/v3/repos///statuses/ 
.. works  fine.

The permission settings for GitHub token were the problem; Github really need to fix their exception handling; 404 it is not!

Comment: If I use that base, nothing happens.. At least with api/v3, I get a HTTP 200 - which suggests the endpoint is there .. When I post a payload, to the same url, I get 404... It could be exception handling on github server?

Comment: it might be access issue, maybe you have no right to push

Comment: To be clear, I am only looking to apply the state of "pending", against a status_check that I wish to create in the same instance. I have the rights to push to the target repo; it's possibly something to do with the fact that I am the PR raiser also? (though I am not trying to mark it as successful, nor close it - which I would be blocked from doing).

Comment: it's better to have separate account for it.

Comment: I finally realized the issue! The token I was using, originally purposed for reporting on another solution, did not have the correct permission to the repository! Thanks @Andriy.. Though please note that this was with the URL I originally posted.

Comment: @OneMoreNerd great, eh, that http status confused everyone ...

Comment: Wasted so much time trying to solve the 404 error... This should be returning HTTP 403